# PHP execute multiple queries and while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am having some difficulty executing multiple queries.

I have been reading about `mysqli_multi_query` however I'm not sure how to implement this into my existing code.

Ideally I need to query two separate tables and display the results within the same while loop. Should this be a do-while, or am I way off?

My current code is;

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

//setup first query
$query = ("SELECT pub_id, title FROM vw_ft_search WHERE pub_id = $id");

//setup second query
$query = ("SELECT phys_desc FROM vw_physical_descriptions WHERE publication_id = $id");

$result = $conn->query($query);

if($result === false) {
    trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $query . ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

        //result from first query
        if (!empty($row['pub_id'])){ echo $row['pub_id'] . '<br />'; }
            else echo "no information" .'<br />';

        //result from first query
        if (!empty($row['title'])){ echo $row['title'] . '<br />'; }
            else echo "no information" .'<br />';

        //result from second query here

    }
```

New to this so any help/advice is appreciated.

Comment: Make one query using `JOIN`. Or `UNION`

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_GET` data directly into a query.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @tadman this is really useful. The problem that I seem to be having as a novice is that there are so many (different and out of date) tutorials out there it's hard to find a good one to follow.

Comment: [PHP the Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) is a great place to start. I'll also mention that if you're serious about developing applications you'll want to find a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like  [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) that suits your style and needs, then learn that inside and out. The core PHP library is extremely primitive and requires a lot of grunt work to get anything non-trivial done with it, whereas a good framework will do most of the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these are 1:1 records you should try to `JOIN` your queries instead. Also, I fixed your SQL injection

```
$id = $conn->real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$query = "SELECT vfs.pub_id, vfs.title, vpd.phys_desc
    FROM vw_ft_search vfs
        INNER JOIN vw_physical_descriptions vpd ON vfs.pub_id = vpd.publication_id
    WHERE vfs.pub_id = $id";
```

Comment: It's much better to fix with a placeholder. This *might* have a vulnerability if someone does something dumb between the first line and the second. Still, a step up, go good to catch that!

Comment: thanks @Machavity this is working. Can I just ask, why ave you prefixed them `vfs.` and `vpd.` - can they be prefixed anything?

Comment: I aliased the table names and fields. It's a good coding practice because you never guess which table you're referencing. If you choose not to alias the tables you can just write the full table name in front

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a join statement:

```
SELECT pub_id, title, phys_desc FROM vw_ft_search 
JOIN vw_physical_descriptions ON vw_physical_descriptions.publication_id=vw_ft_search.pub_id
WHERE vw_ft_search.pub_id = $id"
```

The JOIN mushes the table together, the ON tells the server how to match the data up.

Answer (score 0):

Can `$result = $conn->query($query);` handle multi query? Maybe you should be using

```
$result = $conn->multi_query($query);
```